# git remote add name server : what is name?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is `name` in `git remote add name server` just a label to reference the locally configured remote or does it create something on the remote git like a folder? The typical example of `name` I see is "origin" and I'm used to see origin as a container/folder for branches and this lead me to think that what you provide in `name` creates a folder on the remote git server.

BTW is the following a possible way to create a containing folder for a branch when doing the first push?

```
git push -u origin master:folder/remote_branch
```

I was wondering if anything like the following (screenshot from azure devops) is achievable via git commands or if it is something proprietary

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> does it create something on the remote git like a folder?

No.  That command updates the `.git/config` file which git uses to figure out where to look when you use `git pull` or `git push`.

> BTW is the following a possible way to create a containing folder for a branch when doing the first push?
>
> git push -u origin master:folder/remote_branch

No, there isn't a way for you to create a folder structure through git.  What your command would do is create a new branch on *origin* called *folder/remote_branch* and you would be pushing the new commits from your local *master* branch to the origin's *folder/remote_branch*.

Comment: So "folder/remote_branch" would all make up the name of the remote branch and not have "folder" as the container for possibly numerous folders?

Answer (score 1):

[magikid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62308492/1256452) to your main question is fine.

As for the "folder", though: in Git's "eyes", branch names aren't folder-structures at all, but to accommodate operating systems in which they're *stored* that way, Git makes sure that you cannot create a branch named "a" if you have a branch named "a/b".

What this means is that *Git* treats the names as flat strings: you have `folder/remote_branch`—just a plain string—as the name of the branch, but other software can, if it chooses, collect together all names that being with `folder/` and display them indented as you showed, with collapse/expand buttons.

Comment: ok, so the folder shown in azure devops is really just a visualization help but truth is that it is part of a branch name